# How to convert data frame headers from excel values to date format

Tags: r

I've imported a data set from an xlsx file

The excel file consists of 2 text columns and 72 value columns which is month wise sales.

Excel Data:

[image]

After the data is imported into R using the following script, the data looks like the below.

```
TableA = read.xlsx("TableA.xlsx", sheetName = 'Sheet1', check.names=FALSE)
```

[image]

I'm trying to convert the column names in R similar to the excel view but couldn't.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Script I used:

```
names(Table1[,3:74]) = lapply(as.numeric(names(Table1[,3:74])), as.Date,origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Comment: Please share your data with `dput(TableA)`. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a literal answer to your question, but *I don't recommend it*.

```r
Table1 <- data.frame("43220"=c(1,7), "43251"=c(2,8), check.names = FALSE)
Table1
#   43220 43251
# 1     1     2
# 2     7     8
as.Date(as.integer(names(Table1)), origin = "1899-12-30")
# [1] "2018-04-30" "2018-05-31"
format(as.Date(as.integer(names(Table1)), origin = "1899-12-30"), format="%b %y")
# [1] "Apr 18" "May 18"
names(Table1) <- format(as.Date(as.integer(names(Table1)), origin = "1899-12-30"), format="%b %y")
Table1
#   Apr 18 May 18
# 1      1      2
# 2      7      8
```

In general I discourage the presence of "data-like things" as column names, unless being shown in a report or rendering of the data. It can often be easier (but not always) dealing with data in a "long" format, where the date is a value of a column, not a column name:

```r
Table1 <- data.frame("43220"=c(1,7), "43251"=c(2,8), check.names = FALSE)
Table1long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(Table1, everything(), names_to = "date")
Table1long
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   date  value
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 43220     1
# 2 43251     2
# 3 43220     7
# 4 43251     8
Table1long$date <- as.Date(as.integer(Table1long$date), origin = "1899-12-30")
Table1long
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   date       value
#   <date>     <dbl>
# 1 2018-04-30     1
# 2 2018-05-31     2
# 3 2018-04-30     7
# 4 2018-05-31     8
```

where the `date` column is now actually number-like values, where things like addition and differencing work naturally. Once you are done munging/calculating on the data and are ready for reports, then you can format it with `format(., format="%b %y")` or such.

(An alternative to `tidyr` is `reshape2`:

```r
reshape2::melt(Table1, -seq_len(ncol(Table1)), variable.name = "date")
#    date value
# 1 43220     1
# 2 43220     7
# 3 43251     2
# 4 43251     8
```